# How to fix the error when installing vue-cli

Tags: npm, vuejs2, coffeescript, vue-cli

when I run the command `npm install -g vue-cli` I get the following warning, apparently I have no errors

[image: vue-cli installation stack trace]

but when executing
`vue init webpack my-project`
or
`vue --version`

this pops up

[image: vue --version]

Comment: Not sure if it's going to make a difference but did you try ```npm install -g @vue/cli```?

Answer (score 0):

As the docs say `vue-cli` is the old package name

> Warning regarding Previous Versions
>
> The package name changed from vue-cli to @vue/cli. If you have the previous vue-cli (1.x or 2.x) package installed globally, you need to uninstall it first with npm uninstall vue-cli -g or yarn global remove vue-cli.

cf: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html

As manu said try using `npm install -g @vue/cli`

Answer (score 0):

use command : sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
as the error is because of permission

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be cause by permission, you could run powershell with admin then run the command `npm i -g @vue/cli`